# Mean +/- 1 standard deviation always have majority of the values?

Tags: probability-distributions, means, standard-deviation

Let us say that we have a random probability distribution and we know it's `Mean` and it's `Standard Deviation`.

My question is that, is it necessarily true that the majority of values (>= 50%) in that particular probability distribution will lie between: -

$$\mu  \pm  1 \sigma$$

Are there any probability distribution where this is not the case? Also is there any proof for the same?

Comment: Try $P(X=-k)=P(X=+k)=0.4999$ and $P(X=0)=0.0002$ and find $\mu\pm 1\sigma$

Comment: This may be relevant to your interests: [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).